# Kafka SASL/Plain with SSL options and Kafka SASL/Scram with SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I have few questions on the above topics, Please can you help on understanding these things.

1. SASL/Plain can be used with and with out SSL. So if not use SSL then data is encrypted
   and secured?
2. SASL/Plain with SSL then data will be secured and encrypted from both sides like from
   client to server and server to client data? If encrypted from both side then how?
3. If only one way to the above question i.e from server to client encryption how above the data encryption from client to server?
4. Can we use two way SSL along with SASL/Plain or SASL/Scram?
5. If yes to the above question[4], In two way SSL, As we providing certificate from client side, this certificate it self providing the identity of client/user then why we need user name password again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I understand question 1. `SASL_PLAINTEXT` is plaintext. It is not using SSL. Similar for question 2. But yes, SSL requires asymmetric certificates for bidirectional communication. That answer is not unique to Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you don't see SSL, then data is exchanged in plaintext. With SASL/Plain that include your password!
2. Yes, with SSL both the client and server encrypt data when they send anything over the network
3. Not applicable
4. Yes you can and it is usually even recommended!
5. Both [SASL](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl) and [SSL](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_ssl) can be used to authenticate users. You can use the mechanism you prefer. See the Kafka docs for details how to use them.

I recommend you check the [Security section](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security) in the Kafka documentation that covers all these topics and gives examples.